# Is grid something defined on the JavaScript language?

Tags: javascript

I am confused about why this code works. Especially the part of `grid.onclick = function(e) {...};` . At first, I thought it won't work because the developer didn't define `grid` first, but it works. Can someone explain it to me? I don't think grid is something defined in the language.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    table {
       border-collapse: collapse;
     }
     th, td {
       border: 1px solid black;
       padding: 4px;
     }
     th {
       cursor: pointer;
     }
     th:hover {
       background: yellow;
     }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table id="grid">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-type="number">Age</th>
        <th data-type="string">Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>John</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Pete</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>Ann</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>Eugene</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Ilya</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script>

    grid.onclick = function(e) {
      if (e.target.tagName != 'TH') return;

      let th = e.target;
      // if TH, then sort
      // cellIndex is the number of th:
      //   0 for the first column
      //   1 for the second column, etc
      sortGrid(th.cellIndex, th.dataset.type);
    };

    function sortGrid(colNum, type) {
      let tbody = grid.querySelector('tbody');

      let rowsArray = Array.from(tbody.rows);

      // compare(a, b) compares two rows, need for sorting
      let compare;

      switch (type) {
        case 'number':
          compare = function(rowA, rowB) {
            return rowA.cells[colNum].innerHTML - rowB.cells[colNum].innerHTML;
          };
          break;
        case 'string':
          compare = function(rowA, rowB) {
            return rowA.cells[colNum].innerHTML > rowB.cells[colNum].innerHTML ? 1 : -1;
          };
          break;
      }

      // sort
      rowsArray.sort(compare);

      tbody.append(...rowsArray);
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you create a HTML element with id `grid` and don't have `"use strict"` at the top of your JS file `grid` will be defined as a variable referring to that element.

Comment: @mousetail even with "use strict" you'd get it defined.